# Get filename from Content-Disposition

Tags: java, http, jsp, content-disposition

I'm uploading a blob file from an HTML form to a database using JSP. I need to insert the filename into DB. I know that the filename is stored in the [Content-Disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition), how could I get that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you uploaded the file using JavaEE 6 with `HttpServletRequest.getPart`:

```
Part part = request.getPart("xxx"); // input type=file name=xxx
String disposition = part.getHeader("Content-Disposition");
String fileName = disposition.replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"?([^\"]+)\"?.*$", "$1");
```

See [Part](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html).

---

As @Marc mentioned I did not treat URL encoding. (He also made the quotes around the filename optional.)

```
fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

Not checked, but HTTP encoding for headers should be the default ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Thanks ! Just in case someone else tries this : it worked for me using Apache CXF rest controller and getting the "part" as an attachment from a MultipartBody object.

Comment: You'd also need to decode the filename as it's (URL?) encoded.

Comment: @Marc thanks, not tested in the wild, but I agree. I have put the blame on you.

Comment: The regex is pretty dangerous. I wanted to get the part `name` entry, so replaced your `filename` with `name`. Still got the `filename` param, as your regex accepts anything before `name=`. I think the only way to parse it is to literally iterate it char by char, understand whether you are inside a string or not (a file name could contain `filename=` substring and mislead you too)

Comment: This worked for me and I think is safer: 1. `String regex = "(?i)^.*; " + paramName +  "=\"?([^\"]+)\"?.*$";`  (`paramName` should be `name` of `filename` or whatever you want to get). Then 2. `return headerLine.replaceFirst(regex, "$1")`;

Comment: The only change is that I added `; ` after your `(?i)^.*`

Comment: Furthermore, I'd change `[^\"]+` to `[^\"]*`, as currently, the regex does not support empty values